# Returning address of inner function vs returning function itself

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the code below `print(first)` returns the address of the `first_child` function which makes sense to me as the `parent()` function returns a reference to `first_child` rather than the `first_child` function itself - that is `parent()` returns `first_child` and not `first_child()`.

Since a reference to the `first_child` function is returned rather than the function itself i don't understand why `print(first())` actually returns the output of the first_child function - "Hi, I am Emma" is displayed. Why/how is it possible to call the `first_child()` function in this way?

```
def parent(num):
    def first_child():
        return "Hi, I am Emma"

    def second_child():
        return "Call me Liam"

    if num == 1:
        return first_child
    else:
        return second_child


first = parent(1)
second = parent(2)

print(first)
print(first())
```

Comment: `first` is not the address of anything, it is another name for the function that you originally named `first_child`. So, there is no wonder that you get its output when calling it.

Comment: "Since a reference to the first_child function is returned rather than the function itself" there is no such distinction in Python. You are always working with references to objects. A function is just like any other object.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first understand that: In Python, functions are first class citizens. They can - and do - behave like normal variables.

Forget all about C or Java functions. Think of a python function as just another variable - except you can invoke it - i.e. `f()` is meaningful for the `f` variable.

Now let's get back to your question, `parent` returns `first_child` or `second_child` - these are like variables. Now when you take one of these variables and put `()` after them, the variable is invoked. This invocation ends up evaluating to the strings you had defined inside `parent` - and hence you get "Hi I am Emma"

You have to understand that "a reference to the function" is as good as "the function itself" in python.

If you want some more gory details, check out: https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/function-as-objects-in-python-d5215e6d1b0d